# How to send messages from web-service to Android clients?

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-c2dm

I have a PHP web-service, and Android client. I need to make ability to send messages from service for my Android client. How can I make this mechanism?

Comment: [C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) or [Airship](http://urbanairship.com/docs/android-client-push.html)

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have implemented a push mechanism, or using an external one, such as Google [C2DM](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html), which is available for Android (I have not tested it myself, last time I checked it, it was in a beta state), the only way left is use a polling mechanism (ask every so often the web service).